# How to install Adode Flash on a live USB?

Tags: live-usb, flash, adobe

I'm running Ubuntu 13.04 on my computer from a live USB.  I'm not able to watch Youtube videos.  Am I able to install adobe flash and if so how do I add it to the live USB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to enable persistance, if you want to install once and use it after reboot. Please check this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD/Persistence#Introduction (Thanks @Henry Gibson)

And you have to enable multiverse source.

`Applications`->`System Tools`->`Preferences`->`Software & Updates`.

Select `Ubuntu Software` tab and select the entry which `(multiverse)`

Now, execute these commands to install Flashplugin in Ubuntu 13.04

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
```

Comment: I thought that default live USBs didn't have persistence between boots. Do you not need to set up persistence?

Comment: Hello and thanks for your help. Let me explain the situation.  My hard drive failed so my friend instructed me to b

Comment: ugin-installer (11.2.202.280ubuntu0.12.10.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-3.8.0-19-generic
 linux-image-extra-3.8.0-19-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
Not sure what to do now:-(.

Comment: Can you update this error in your question itself?

Comment: I'm not sure how  to update my question...all I see is edit.

Comment: Yes. Edit the question and include the error message in the question itself.

Comment: After do this, If I copy the content of the pendrive into a new pendrive, it will persist? sorry by my ignorance